# Do members answer questions privately?

Tags: discussion

I have code which deals with linked lists, and I am getting an error at compile time due to the fact that I have something pointing to a structure, but the error states that it is not a struct (it is definitely a structure :) ). I have already asked multiple people to debug it and no one can find the answer.

I was just wondering is there somewhere on this forum that I could post code privately as I have put a lot of work into it as it is more difficult than that is required, and I don't want my work taken by other students.

I'm not sure if posting snippets of the code is the answer as, like I said, everyone that has tried to spot the error has failed.

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a forum.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a public question-and-answer site; if you don't want your work taken, don't post it here.  You can post snippets of code, sure, but that would require you to narrow down the problem to a certain section of code (which is a good thing, really, code dumps are usually frowned upon)

Comment: Bit confused about the downvotes here, I think this is a valid support question from a newcomer (it's not a feature request, there isn't much to disagree with).

Comment: @Yannis: agreed. The *question* is valid on Meta, whether or not people think one should be able to do this.

Comment: "and I don't want my work taken by other students." I find it so cute when beginners think their source code is worth millions (even despite the errors they come here to fix).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No.

Stack Overflow lives from the contributions of its users and the fact that those contributions are public. You're asking people to do work that serves nobody (but you), and that's not what people come here for.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot delete the question as it is answered I was wondering could you flag it please.

Comment: @Eamonn there is no need to delete the question.

Comment: @Eamonn why, it's a valid question, downvoting is just indication people disagree with the opinion

Comment: Thanks joe but I think its for the best as people seem to be getting annoyed. I will need to look at the rules before posting again.

Comment: Joe and bummi thanks very much for your feedback

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes; on Meta, they typically mean "I disagree" rather than the usual "This is a Bad Question". It's kind of an in-grown habit on Meta and *very* hard to loose.

Answer (score -15):

I think that a compilation error does not require that you would show all your code. Sometimes it is enough to present the full error message and you will directed in right way.:)

It is much worse when a long listing of code is shown but the full error message is absent.:)